# Label for formula field in 3rd column of PageBlock is wrapping

Tags: visualforce, formula-field, pageblock, label, pageblocksectionitem

No matter what my formula fields label is wrapping.  It has plenty of room to unwrap.  The PageBlock it's in has 3 columnns in it.

[image: There is a wrapping issue with the label in the 3rd column for my formual field]

This is my formula field

```
    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Costs" id="CostsSection" columns="3">  
           <!-- Costs-->
           <!-- before position-->
           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem HelpText="{!$ObjectType.Application__c.fields.Rpt_Position_Support_Prior_to_STAR__c.inlineHelpText}">
               {!$ObjectType.Application__c.fields.Rpt_Position_Support_Prior_to_STAR__c.label}
               <apex:inputField id="beforePosition" value="{!Application__c.Rpt_Position_Support_Prior_to_STAR__c}" />
           </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
           <!-- after position -->
           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="afterPositions" HelpText="{!$ObjectType.Application__c.fields.Rpt_Position_Support_After_STAR__c.inlineHelpText}">
               {!$ObjectType.Application__c.fields.Rpt_Position_Support_After_STAR__c.label}
               <apex:inputField id="afterPosition" value="{!Application__c.Rpt_Position_Support_After_STAR__c}" />
           </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 

           <!-- FTE Cost -->
           <apex:pageBlockSectionItem dataStyleClass="FTECost" HelpText="{!$ObjectType.Application__c.fields.rpt_FTE_Hourly_Wages_Saved__c.inlineHelpText}">
               {!$ObjectType.Application__c.fields.rpt_FTE_Hourly_Wages_Saved__c.label}
               <apex:outputField id="FTEWages" value="{!Application__c.rpt_FTE_Hourly_Wages_Saved__c}" />
           </apex:pageBlockSectionItem> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```

Comment: Please provide the full code.

Comment: editted to include all of the code for the PageBlockSection

Comment: What's in your style class ("FTECost")?

Comment: I was using that to hide pageBlockSectionItems.  I opted to disable fields instead.  Basically, I can remove them.

Comment: I removed them because they are unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapping of these columns are handled by Salesforce itself when pageBlockSectionItems are converted to td's and subsequently additional styling classes are added to them.

One sure way to prevent wrapping of text is to provide inline css for labels:

```
<label for="beforePosition" style="white-space: nowrap;">{!$ObjectType.Application__c.fields.rpt_FTE_Hourly_Wages_Saved__c.label}</label>
```

This will override styling applied by salesforce.

Comment: beautiful!  I also was able to do a number of other CSS mods to the text.   Invaluable info.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad it helped!